# Use of Regexp or substring in Suitescript

Tags: suitescript2.0

I was wondering how to use regexp in Suitescript?

The use case is, I have the url of a page returned as a variable once it is converted to string

var urlPage=JSON.stringify(window.location)

The url is in the format https://tstdrv.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/purchord.nl?whence=

I was wanting to extract everything between the last '/' and the '.nl' (essentially, trying to get the record type)

I have tried using url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')) though I can't find how to specify the end of the substring to return

I was thinking maybe Regexp might be a better way to go (once I muck around with this to work out what pattern would be applicable here) though looking online, I can't see how to incorporate that into Suitescript

What would be the correct way to use regexp in this sort of scenario?

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf?retiredLocale=nl

If you take the index of the last '/' and the index of .nl, you can take the characters of everything between / and .nl. Keep it simple is the key.